Can I weight my branches in a decision tree by their variable importance with rpart?
I have a decision tree model made with rpart of the form tree_model <-rpart(y~x1+x2, data = df).
I can prune and plot the tree as well as the variable importance with the following code:
best <- tree_model$cptable[which.min(tree_model$cptable[,"xerror"]),"CP"]

pruned_tree <- prune(tree_model, cp=best)

rpart.plot(pruned_tree, box.palette = "Blues",yesno=2,extra=1,)

var_importance <- vip::vip(tree_model, num_features = 10)

print(var_importance)

What I would like is to be able to display the variable importance within my branching diagram by, for example, weighting the branches of the tree. Does anyone have experience or ideas for this?
Thank you!
So far, I have just overlaid the plots by making the tree transparent. But its a mediocre fix at best.
